# html body height issue

Tags: html, css, height

There is no height specified for body tag but why is it taking some amount of height when I see in inspect element?

here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/9TzEC/3/

And here is the example screen 
[image]

Comment: You should really never use tables for design purposes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. That was happening because of the table added inside the "content_wrap" div. this is was not considering the table inside it so I added a blank div around the table then it is working as child of the div "content_wrap".

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9TzEC/7/

Answer (score 0):

Look to the left of the jsFiddle screen, uncheck "Normalized CSS"

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/LwBLH/1/

Answer (score 0):

@Sowmya every block tag/element having auto height, If content will increase apparently element height will increase , less content=less height, large content= long height !!

Comment: Right i knw.. but y is body taking the fixed height here. Other page works fine with the same css but different html structure but only in this html this height is the problem. Check this fiddle, here body is taking the auto height properly.. http://jsfiddle.net/9TzEC/5/

Comment: it's not fixed height, body having default min-height=screen-height, may be your screen size have 845px height or something like that, just try to increase content, if body height increases then it's not a fix height..!

Answer (score 0):

add this css to the end of css file

```
.content_wrap {overflow:auto;}
```

this is because of the floating table in this div. if you need I will explain it in detail just ask ;)